# Javascript - Return only unique values in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects where I want to return only the unique objects based on their object Id.

I've tried to loop in the existing array `data` then find if the element was already add to a newly created array `arr` which should contain only the unique values, but it didn't work with me and I believe that I am missing something here or there.

**Here is the current array :**

```
          [
        {
          "objectId": "WMtwbyhFI6",
          "cuisineNameEn": "Cafe",
          "ordersNo": 20,
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "QJSNTMpq5F",
          "ordersNo": 24,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Italian",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "iLXKswFRGa",
          "ordersNo": 5,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Japanese",
          "hidden": true
        },
        {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "QJSNTMpq5F",
          "ordersNo": 24,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Italian",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false,
        },
        {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        },
         {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        },
         {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        }
      ]
```

**However, this is what I want to return :**

```
 [
        {
          "objectId": "WMtwbyhFI6",
          "cuisineNameEn": "Cafe",
          "ordersNo": 20,
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "iLXKswFRGa",
          "ordersNo": 5,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Japanese",
          "hidden": true
        },
        {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "QJSNTMpq5F",
          "ordersNo": 24,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Italian",
          "hidden": false
        }
      ]
```

I've tried the following:

```
 var arr = [];
  data.forEach((el)=>{
  if (arr.indexOf(el.objectId) === -1) {
    arr.push(el)
  }
 })
```

However, it didn't work.

Comment: @JanS not a duplicate, please read the post carefully, I am willing to return a full object not only an element !!!

Comment: @MathRobin not a duplicate I believe he wants to return the object not the element.

Comment: `indexOf()` won't inspect properties inside the array elements. It can only check whole element equality

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski I don't think it is a duplicate as except one all the  answers  are using some library

Comment: Do you want to return the first or the last found one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`reduce()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
data.reduce((acc, x) =>
   acc.concat(acc.find(y => y.ordersNo === x.ordersNo) ? [] : [x])
 , []);
```

`reduce` goes through the array, and for each element it calls the provided function with accumulator (the return value of the previous call) and the current element. `concat` adds the current element to the accumulator if it doesn't exist there yet. `find` checks if the current element exists in the accumulator by comparing the `ordersNo` properties.

Demo:

```js
const data =           [
        {
          "objectId": "WMtwbyhFI6",
          "cuisineNameEn": "Cafe",
          "ordersNo": 20,
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "QJSNTMpq5F",
          "ordersNo": 24,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Italian",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "iLXKswFRGa",
          "ordersNo": 5,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Japanese",
          "hidden": true
        },
        {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "QJSNTMpq5F",
          "ordersNo": 24,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Italian",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false,
        },
        {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        },
         {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        },
         {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        }
      ];
 
 console.log(data.reduce((acc, x) =>
   acc.concat(acc.find(y => y.ordersNo === x.ordersNo) ? [] : [x])
 , []));
```

Comment: Can you please give some details ? I want to understand

Comment: Array.prototype.reduce() is the most under-valued array function. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @TJBlackman If you like this function, you would probably like functional programming. I recommend learning [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/) – it's a functional library for JavaScript.

Comment: @TJBlackman `reduce` is rather the most abused array function. It makes no sense to use an accumulator here. Without reduce: `(acc => data.forEach(el => acc.find(e => e.objectId === el.ObjectId) || acc.push(el)) || acc)([])`

Comment: @JonasW. - Did you even read the question? You're script simply puts ALL the data into a new array. The OP is trying to create an array of UNIQUE values with respect to the `objectId` property. It is 100% appropriate to use an accumulator here.

Comment: @TJBlackman [well...](http://jsbin.com/wenobinuge/edit?console)(okay there was a small typo that caused a malfunction), however there is still no jeed to reduce.

Comment: `find()` is expensive also on large data set when run every iteration

Comment: @charlietfl OP didn't say that they have a large data set. There's no need to do premature optimisation.

Comment: Just suggesting there are more performant approaches to do it

Answer (score 4):

You may `filter` the array and use a Set of ids to check for dupes:

```
const result = array.filter( (hash => obj => !(hash.has(obj.objectId) || hash.add(obj.objectId) && false))(new Set));
```

Comment: @hamza you may read about `closures`, `IIFE`, `Set`, `short-circuiting`,  `logical operators`, `Array.prototype.filter`

Comment: Mind-blowing :). Why does `new Set` without parens returns a set?

Comment: @wostex cause you can omit the `()` on instance construction with `new`

Comment: *Why* omit the `()` here? Including them seems like it would only make things more clear, and it just makes your code 2 characters longer.

Comment: @bsinky why not? I dont think `new Set()` is more readable then `new Set`

Comment: @JonasWilms Can you pls explain the code like order of execution and how it is working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array#reduce` and create an object with `objectId` as the key and the object as the values. Once, you have your object, extract all values to get the unique objects using `Object.values()`.

```js
var data = [ { "objectId": "WMtwbyhFI6", "cuisineNameEn": "Cafe", "ordersNo": 20, "hidden": false }, { "objectId": "QJSNTMpq5F", "ordersNo": 24, "cuisineNameEn": "Italian", "hidden": false }, { "objectId": "iLXKswFRGa", "ordersNo": 5, "cuisineNameEn": "Japanese","hidden": true }, { "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE", "ordersNo": 6, "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food", "hidden": false }, { "objectId": "QJSNTMpq5F", "ordersNo": 24, "cuisineNameEn": "Italian", "hidden": false }, { "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE", "ordersNo": 6, "cuisineNameEn":"Fast Food", "hidden": false }, { "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE", "ordersNo": 6, "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food", "hidden": false, }, { "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE", "ordersNo": 6, "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food", "hidden": false }, { "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE", "ordersNo":6, "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food", "hidden": false }, { "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE", "ordersNo": 6, "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food", "hidden": false }, { "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE", "ordersNo": 6, "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food", "hidden": false } ],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,o) => (r[o.objectId] = o, r),{}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think you should rather use `reduceRight`

Comment: Any specific reason?

Comment: Well, he wanted all the unique objects, so, even this code should work. I get your point.

Answer (score 1):

You should try with filter and Set :

```
result = (function () { // we use an IIFE to isolate everything
    var uniqIds = new Set(); // Set only accepts unique values
    return list.filter(item => { // Array filter returns a new array based on result of callback passed in parameter
        if(!uniqIds.has(item.objectId)) {
            uniqIds.add(item.objectId);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf()` won't work to check similar objects or check properties inside objects. It will only work with object references that are the same

Can use a hashmap object that stores the common property as keys. Following uses `this` argument of `filter` for the hashmap

```js
const res = data.filter(o => !this[o.objectId] && (this[o.objectId]=true), {});

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script>
const data = [
        {
          "objectId": "WMtwbyhFI6",
          "cuisineNameEn": "Cafe",
          "ordersNo": 20,
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "QJSNTMpq5F",
          "ordersNo": 24,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Italian",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "iLXKswFRGa",
          "ordersNo": 5,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Japanese",
          "hidden": true
        },
        {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "QJSNTMpq5F",
          "ordersNo": 24,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Italian",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false,
        },
        {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        },
         {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        },
         {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        }
      ];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this simple solution

```js
function uniqueObjectsArr(array, uniqueValue) {
    var obj = {},
    uniqueArr = [];
    array.forEach(element => {
        obj[element[uniqueValue]] = element;
    });
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            uniqueArr.push(obj[key]);
        }
    }
    return uniqueArr;
}

 myData = uniqueObjectsArr(myData, "objectId");
 console.log(myData);
```

```html
 <script>
 myData = [
        {
          "objectId": "WMtwbyhFI6",
          "cuisineNameEn": "Cafe",
          "ordersNo": 20,
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "QJSNTMpq5F",
          "ordersNo": 24,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Italian",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "iLXKswFRGa",
          "ordersNo": 5,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Japanese",
          "hidden": true
        },
        {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "QJSNTMpq5F",
          "ordersNo": 24,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Italian",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false,
        },
        {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        },
         {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        },
         {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "objectId": "Db0MeihpJE",
          "ordersNo": 6,
          "cuisineNameEn": "Fast Food",
          "hidden": false
        }
      ]
      </script>
```